# What driving or racing game is Percy playing in No Hard Feelings?

Tags: game-identification

In the 2023 comedy film *[No Hard Feelings](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt15671028/)*, there is a scene where Percy (played by Andrew Barth Feldman) is playing a driving or racing video game. He keeps saying, "I’m drifting," as he maneuvers his car. The game shows a road sign that indicates the direction to "AIRPORT ALRICO" or "AIRICO" as Percy drives past it. There’s no HUD visible.

A clip and a screenshot of the game being played:

[image]

[image]

##### What is the name of the driving or racing game that Percy is playing in *No Hard Feelings*?

Comment: The absence of HUD makes me think that's not a real game

Comment: @pinckerman Yes, that’s possible. However, more and more games now provide settings to disable the HUD, like for taking screenshots or video clips.

Comment: I managed to find a longer version of the video playing on the monitor. The physics make it very obvious that it's not a real game: https://www.tiktok.com/@perfectfundos/video/7136713588521291014

Comment: @clsa I would say that should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

It's not a real game, as you can tell by the physics seen in a [longer version of the render.](https://tiktok.com/@perfectfundos/video/7136713588521291014)

Comment: TODO: Download and upload the video to a less intrusive/flashy, more easy-on-the-eyes host than TikTok (imgur? catbox? webmshare?)

Comment: I think it could be [converted to a GIF](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16826/4797) and uploaded to SE Imgur.